# How to add custom item to properties dialog in Eclipse Problems View

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to add custom item to properties dialog in Eclipse Problems View like this:

[image]

I originally thought that adding custom column will do the trick, but obviously it was a wrong idea.

I will be grateful for any ideas. 
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Actually there is a straightforward way how to do it after all - overriding MarkersPropertyPage:

```
public class MyMarkersPropertyPage extends MarkersPropertyPage{ 
@Override
protected Control createContents(final Composite parent)
{
    final Composite c = (Composite) super.createContents(parent);
    createCustomArea(c);

    return c;
}

private void createCustomArea(final Composite parent)
{ // contribution
}
```

...and hide the Eclipse one using activities:

```
    <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
            <activity id="your.activity.id" name="disabledActivity">
            </activity>
    <activityPatternBinding
            activityId="your.activity.id"
            isEqualityPattern="true"
            pattern="org.eclipse.ui.ide/org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerEntry">
      </activityPatternBinding>>
   </extension>
```

Comment: MarkersPropertyPage is an **internal** class. You are violating the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by extending it.

Answer (score 0):

This property page is provided by the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.MarkersPropertyPage` property page.

Looking at the source of `MarkersPropertyPage` it does not support any way to add to the page.

Comment: I came up with a solution after all and edited the question. Thanks for help anyway @greg-449